# lambda aws Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda, aws-lambda-layers

i created a simple lambda function like calling api url and i have import requests library in my lambda function and i downloaded requests library in my local machine with command (pip3 install requests -t ) and zipped the folder and added as a layer in my lambda function but am getting below error.

Here my lambda function:

```
import json
from config import base_url
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    res = requests.get(url=base_url+'todos/1')
    return {
        'statusCode': res.statusCode,
        'body': res.json()
    }
```

config.py file:

```
base_url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
```

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "486a7cda-4162-4809-bcb8-cb12bf640e60",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create your own `requests` layer, please use publicily avaiabile layers witch work out of the box. For example, `request` is provided by [Klayers](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers#python-packages) layers.

In `us-east-1`, for python 3.11, the layer arn is:

```
arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p311-requests:1
```

You can find corresponding arns for other python versions and regions.